# How to update nginx?

Tags: nginx, debian

I have the 1.2.1 version of nginx, I don't know how to upgrade it. I have debian7. I installed it with the nginx-extras packaging

My source.list:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all


apt-get upgrade nginx-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  nginx-common nginx-extras php5-memcache php5-memcached
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Someone can help me ? Thank you

Comment: You may want to use an alternate repo such as dotdeb - https://www.dotdeb.org/ .

Comment: @TanHongTat to OP already has `dotdeb.org` in their `sources.list`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official Debian Wheezy repository, you have already the latest version of nginx https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/nginx

Check out this question to further information on how to update using an alternate repo

https://serverfault.com/questions/597756/how-to-upgrade-nginx-from-1-2-to-1-6-on-debian-7

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Debian always takes more time than other distros before they include package updates into their official sources